# Get Departmenr name from department id using eloquent laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I have this user table

```
id | name |      email     | department_id

1    user 1  xyz@gmail.com        2
```

and this is department table

```
id |  department_name 

1      Admin 
2      Account
```

there is salary table :

```
id |  user_id |  basic_pay

1        1          5000
```

I have this employee relation in salary model

```
class Salary extends Model
{
   public function employee(){
      return $this->belongsTo('App\User','user_id','id');
   }
}
```

I want to get department name also to which user is associated

```
  $Data =  Salary::where('id',$id)->with('employee')->first();
```

but presently i can only get department_id with the help of employee relation.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried adding a relatonship from employee to department? called ```department()``` then using ```with('employee.department')``` in your query?

Answer (score 1):

You could add another relationship to the User model called `department` which would look like this:

```
public function department()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Department::class);
}
```

and then user dot notation documented here: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#nested-eager-loading. Which would look like this

```
Salary::where('id', $id)->with('employee.department')->first();
```

Additionally, you can simplify this by using the find method, which would look like this:

```
Salary::with('employee.department')->find($id);
```

You would need to reverse the other of methods due to the fact that find will return the model, in this case a Salary model.

If you do not know if the Salary will exist you may want to use `findOrFail` documented here https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent#not-found-exceptions

Answer (score 0):

```
Data =  Salary::where('id',$id)->with('employee.department')->first();
```

In Your Employee model add relation like Below

```
   public function department(){
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Department','department_id');
}
```